# request.getResponse() is getting error

Tags: c#

This is my code which is returning the expected output on my friend's PC, but not on mine.

We are both working with Visual Studio 2017 Community:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwlYT.jpg)

This is the code that will return latitude and longitude of the entered address:

[enter image description here][2]

The first time it works fine but after that its throwing (403 forbidden error !!! / mainly problem is on the request.getResponse())

```
    private static String[] x = new String[3];

    public static String[] GetFirstLastName(string address)
    {
        try { 
        string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&sensor=false";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        // request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        // request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var ds = new DataSet("Employee");
                ds.ReadXml(reader);

                DataRow dr = null;

                var dt = new DataTable("Employee");
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("Latitude", typeof (string)),
                        new DataColumn("Longitude", typeof (string))
                    });

                int i = 0;

                try
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["result"].Rows)
                    {
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                   return x;
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["result"].Rows)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        string geometry_id = ds.Tables["geometry"].Select("result_id = " + row["result_id"])[0]["geometry_id"].ToString();

                        dr = ds.Tables["location"].Select("geometry_id = " + geometry_id)[0];

                        dt.Rows.Add(dr["lat"], dr["lng"]);

                        //  Console.WriteLine(dr["lat"].ToString() + " " + dr["lng"].ToString());
                        i = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                x[0] = dr["lat"].ToString();
                x[1] = dr["lng"].ToString();

                reader.Close();
            }

            // request.Timeout = 0;
            // request.Abort();
            response.Close();
            return x;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        x[0] = "";
        x[1] = "";
        return x;
    }
}

public static String[] GetFirstLastName1(string address)
{
        try
        {
            string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address + "&sensor=false";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            //  request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            // request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //   request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var ds = new DataSet("Employee");
                    ds.ReadXml(reader);

                    DataRow dr = null;

                    var dt = new DataTable("Employee");
                    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]
                    {
                new DataColumn("Latitude", typeof (string)),
                new DataColumn("Longitude", typeof (string))
                    });

                    int i = 0;

                    try
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["result"].Rows)
                        {

                        }


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

                        return x;
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["result"].Rows)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            string geometry_id = ds.Tables["geometry"].Select("result_id = " + row["result_id"])[0]["geometry_id"].ToString();

                            dr = ds.Tables["location"].Select("geometry_id = " + geometry_id)[0];

                            dt.Rows.Add(dr["lat"], dr["lng"]);

                            //  Console.WriteLine(dr["lat"].ToString() + " " + dr["lng"].ToString());
                            i = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    x[0] = dr["lat"].ToString();
                    x[1] = dr["lng"].ToString();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                //// request.Timeout = 0;
                ///   request.Abort();
                response.Close();
                return x;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            x[0] = "";
            x[1] = "";
            return x;
        }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0;

        for (;;)
        {
            String x = Console.ReadLine();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                String[] y = GetFirstLastName(x);

                Console.WriteLine(y[0] + " " + y[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                String[] y = GetFirstLastName1(x);

                Console.WriteLine(y[0] + " " + y[1]);
            }

            i++;
        }
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

/*(Same Code above)

```
enter code here
```

///My Friends Output
   /// My Output
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeDcz.png */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to see you've joined StackOverflow!

**Now a 403 error occurs usually not in relation to a syntax error in your code but in relation to the response received from Google's servers.**

Now Google in particular is very restrictive on how many API calls you can make a day (Google makes a lot of money off developers who pay for lots of API calls). [This page contains the limits.](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis) If you've made more than the numbers in here, that's why you're getting the error and you'll have to wait until tomorrow. Do keep in mind not to send too many http requests and accidentally DOS them, as they'll blacklist you for this.

Make sure you are not caching their page or storing the js script locally as this will also cause a blacklist.

Make sure you use `https:` and not `http:` here.

Comment: *Make sure you are not caching their page or storing the js script locally as this will also cause a blacklist.*, How do you know this? Any documentation?